# How to add a newline for the text that just get's pushed to a new line because there is no more space for it

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, textarea, newline

---

Update:

Solved with php plus a html form:

Html:

```
<form method="POST" action="echoline.php">
<textarea class="font-face" rows="2" style="width: 480px; height: 150px;" name="textbox_input" wrap="hard">
  At ....you will find free Web-building  ......... ..............</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Php:

```
<?php
$array = explode("\n", $_POST['textbox_input']);
foreach ($array as $row){
echo '<br />' . $row;
}
```

---

How to add a newline for the text string that goes into a textarea that just get's pushed to a new line because there is no more space for it to be on that line?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/pYTjR/11/
```

The NnnnnnnNnnnnnnnnnn need to be on a new line in array.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function check(){
    var lines = $('#links').val().split(/\n/);
    var texts = []
    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
            texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
        }
    //var links = texts;
    //var str = links[i];
    //alert(i+"-  "+str);
    }
    for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        alert(i+"-  "+texts[i]);
    }
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

<textarea id="links" name="upload" cols=80 rows=10  style="width: 300px; height: 150px;">
www.example.com/book111.pdf
www.example.com/book222.pdf NnnnnnnNnnnnnnnnnn
www.example.com/book333.pdf

www.example.com/book444.pdf
www.example.com/book555.pdf
</textarea>
<input type="submit" id="getsize" name="getsize" value="textarea to array" onclick= "check()"/>         
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion take a bit of time to learn how to use jsfiddle properly it helps others greatly when trying to debug issues.

Comment: I had some problems with the code when I moved the script to JavaScript area.